# AngularJS Show Hide Element only on Page Refresh

Tags: angularjs

ive got a Problem. I want  to Show Hide Menuitems when the User ist logged in or logged out.

So i wrote a homecontroller : `scope.UserLoggedIn = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('loginToken') != null;`

And in my Index.html this :

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="pull-left"><a href="/Home">HOME</a> </li>
            <li class="pull-right" data-ng-show="UserLoggedIn"><a href="/#/Login" data-ng-click="Logout()">LOGOUT</a></li>
            <li class="pull-right" data-ng-hide="UserLoggedIn"><a href="/#/Login">LOGIN</a></li>
            <li class="pull-right" data-ng-hide="UserLoggedIn"><a href="/#/register">REGISTER</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The Property is set correct but the Menu disappears only if i refresh the Page. When i logout, i have to Refresh the Page to render the new Menu.

I think, im doing it wrong :/

Comment: Where is the `hometController` defined. Is it part of $routeProvider definition? When is this value set. You can try to use a method instead of property so that evaluation happens at correct time. Some thing like `scope.UserLoggedIn = function () { return $window.sessionStorage.getItem('loginToken') != null;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not detailed about your, `homeController` declaration and when do you set the variable.

But one way to fix this issue would be to use a function instead. Something like

```
scope.UserLoggedIn = function () { 
   return $window.sessionStorage.getItem('loginToken') != null;
}
```

This function would get called every time digest cycle happens so you would always get the correct value.

Comment: Its in the div directly in the index.html where the Menu is declared